# Next / Prev href buttons with javascript incrementing url

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner with javascript. 
I have a next and previous button on a main index page, and I want each of them to go to the next or previous html page in a sequence. The sequenced html pages appear in an iframe. I'm trying to figure out the correct and most efficient way of doing this.

Pages are named in sequence 01.html, 02.html, 03.html etc.

Here are my buttons.

```
<a
    class="btn"
    onclick="decrementPg();"
    href="<script>prvPgURL</script>"
    target="iframe">
    <i class="icon-chevron-left"></i> Back </a>

<a
    class="btn"
    onclick="incrementPg();"
    href="<script>nxtPgURL</script>"
    target="_blank"> Next
    <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> </a>
```

Here is my Javascript between the head tags, which I am positive is totally wrong.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var curPg = 0;
var nxtPg = 1;
var prvPg = 0;
var nxtPgURL = "0"+nxtPg+".html";
var prvPgURL = "0"+curPg+".html";

function incrementPg() {
    if(curPg == 0){
        alert('curPg: == 0');
    curPg = (curPg +1);
    nxtPg = (nxtPg +1); 
    } else {
        alert('curPg: !== 0');
    curPg = (curPg +1);
    nxtPg = (nxtPg +1);
    prvPg = (prvPg +1);
    }
alert('curPg: ' +curPg +', nxtPg: '+ nxtPg +', prvPg: '+ prvPg +', prvPgURL: '+ prvPgURL +', nxtPgURL: '+ nxtPgURL);
}

function decrementPg() {
    if(curPg == 0){
        alert('curPg: == 0');
    curPg = (curPg +1);
    nxtPg = (nxtPg +1); 
    } else {
        alert('curPg: !== 0');
    curPg = (curPg -1);
    nxtPg = (nxtPg -1);
    prvPg = (prvPg -1);
    }
 alert('curPg: ' +curPg +', nxtPg: '+ nxtPg +', prvPg'+ prvPg);
}
</script>
```

I'm sure there must be a much easier way to do this.

Comment: I think this part is wrong: `href="<script>prvPgURL</script>"`
If I change the target in the A tag on the button to go to a blank page, the URL looks like this: `http://www.server.com/player/<script>nxtPgURL</script>`

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of work for just emulating the back and forward buttons in javascript. It would be MUCH easier to use the history object instead.

Use `window.history.forward()` and `window.history.back()`. [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_forward.asp).

Other than that if you INSIST on doing it the hard way, want you want to do is:

```
var n = 0;
function browserButton(value) {
    window.open((n + value) + '.html', _self);
}
```

And in your html just pass a +1 or -1 to browserButton. Like so

```
<a href="#" alt="back button" onclick="browserButton(-1)">

<a href="#" alt="forward button" onclick="browserButton(1)">
```

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp).

Comment: History object does not work because the forward URL's have not been visited yet. 

I tried your second suggestion, and it does not work.

`<script type="text/javascript">
var n = 0;
function browserButton(value){
alert("n: "+n);
window.open((n+value)'.html', _self);
}
</script> `

My buttons look like:
`<a class="btn" class="btn" href="#" onclick="browserButton(1)" target="iframe"> Next <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> </a>`

If I strip the function down to just an alert, you can see that the function isn;t even being called.

Comment: Your not supposed to set target in your a tag. The target attribute goes on the frame itself. This why its not being called.

Comment: Correction you have the target on the a tag correct but you forgot to actually name the frame itself. Also you might not want to add target on the a tag anyway as that will interfere with the window.open function.

Comment: Please format your code blocks properly. See my edit to learn how it's done. (Adding four spaces to each line of code, or using backticks for inline code)